# Emacs auto-complete-mode cycles focus through every window?

Tags: emacs

When I have autocomplete mode enabled:

```
(global-auto-complete-mode 1)
```

Once I get a few windows open, hitting any key in one window will quickly cycle focus through *all* the windows in the frame.

For example, to recreate:

- Load auto-complete-mode
- Open up 5 or 6 windows in one frame
- Open up a frame editing a Python file (although this appears to happen with other file types too, like `.c`)
- Mash the keyboard. Observe that focus is quickly cycled between the windows.

Here is a video showing the problem: http://gfycat.com/LeafyCleverCommongonolek — notice that I'm typing at a constant rate, but every few characters focus cycles between all the open windows.

If I set:

```
(global-auto-complete-mode nil)
```

Then the problem goes away.

What can I do to fix this?

This is happening with Carbon emacs 24.3.1 installed from Homebrew.

Comment: What does the *message* buffer say? I can't reproduce the behaviour you describe

Comment: Message buffer says nothing… Here's a video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMZ9fbHoyl4 (note: I've got evil, flymake, and a few other things running, but I see exactly the same problem when they are turned off)

Comment: Check if still happens running emacs -Q, which should give you clean configs.

Comment: Nope, definitely doesn't. In fact, it only happens when auto-complete-mode is enabled (ie, commenting out `(global-auto-complete mode 1)` makes the problem go away).

Comment: I think what Bruce Connor meant was, start emacs with `-Q` and then execute only the lines you posted in your question, but no other configuration. This way you can make sure that what you experience isn't an unwanted side effect from something else.

Comment: Oh, sorry — yes, I have also done that too, and I can recreate the problem with only those lines.